# Why do my objects get deconstructed twice after I add their unique_ptr to a vector?

Tags: c++, class, stdvector, unique-ptr

I am trying to make a vector of `unique_ptr`s to the `Example` class and for some reason every time I call `emplace_back()` the objects get deconstructed twice. I think it's easier for you to understand if I just show the code here:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Example;
typedef std::unique_ptr<Example> ExampleUPointer;
std::vector<ExampleUPointer> ExampleList;

class Example {
    short index;
public:
    Example()
        : index (ExampleList.size())
    {
        ExampleList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Example>(*this));
        printf("Example %d was constructed\n", index);
    }
    ~Example() {
        printf("Example %d was deconstructed\n", index);
    }
};
```

Then I proceed to create five objects of the `Example` class in `main()`. This is the output:

```
Example 0 was constructed
Example 1 was constructed
Example 2 was constructed
Example 3 was constructed
Example 4 was constructed
Example 4 was deconstructed
Example 3 was deconstructed
Example 2 was deconstructed
Example 1 was deconstructed
Example 0 was deconstructed
Example 0 was deconstructed
Example 1 was deconstructed
Example 2 was deconstructed
Example 3 was deconstructed
Example 4 was deconstructed
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: To see what is actually happening, I suggest to also print the content of the `this` pointer in the constructor and destructor. Possibly also overwrite the copy constructor and print the addresses of the source and destination.

Comment: You state you create five objects in `main()`.   The code in `main()` is therefore more relevant to your problem than the code you have shown.   If you don't provide that, anyone trying to help you will be forced to resort to guesswork about what your `main()` is *actually* doing.

Comment: @Peter The code in `main()` is literally `Example e0;` to `Example e4;`.

Comment: @phg - Edit the question and provide that information there.   If `main()` is that simple, there's no reason to omit it.   Particularly since omitting it forces people to guess about whether `main()` is doing something funky that is relevant to what you're seeing.

Comment: @phg `printf("Example %d was constructed\n", index);` -- This will now show you the object that is constructed (or destroyed) -- just using integer numbers is worthless for this.  Replace all of that with simply `std::cout << "Example " << this <<  " -> " << index << " was constructed\n";` then make the similar change to the other output statement.  If you had did that originally, you would see that the objects are different / missing from the constructor and destructor messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::unique_ptr` *owns* what it's pointing to. So it doesn't make any sense for the constructor of your object (which has an owner already - whatever is constructing the object) to be able to create a valid unique pointer to itself. And of course that's not what you're doing. Like Sam's answer says, you're creating a brand new `Example` object, a copy, and adding that to the vector.

One option is to have the vector not *own* the objects. Just store a raw pointer in the vector

```cpp
std::vector<Example*> ExampleList;
...
Example()
{
    ExampleList.emplace_back(this);
}
```

This will require you to ensure that the `Example` objects live at least as long as the pointer to it in the vector. You could have the destructor automatically remove it from the vector.

Another option is to have a factory function that creates the object, adds it to the vector (which will then own the object), and return a pointer to it. The lifetime of the object is now maintained by the vector:

```cpp
class Example;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Example>> ExampleList;

class Example {
public:
    static Example *create()
    {
        // Create a new Example object and add it to the vector
        // The unique_ptr in the vector has ownership of the object
        ExampleList.push_back(std::make_unique<Example>());
        // Return a pointer to the object
        return ExampleList.back().get();
    }

private:
    // Can't call directly
    Example() { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you create an object with the int constructor, that constructor creates another completely different object by calling the copy constructor.

```
    Example()
      : index (ExampleList.size())
    {
      ExampleList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Example>(*this)); //<--- here
      printf("Example %d was constructed\n", index);
```

right there.  You make a 2nd object.

So you construct 5 objects with an int constructor, 5 with copy constructor, then destroy 10 objects.

The copied objects have the same index as the int constructed ones.  That is what copy means.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ExampleList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Example>(*this));
```

If you work out, with paper and pencil, what happens here you will discover that a 2nd instance of `Example` gets copy-constructed right here.

However your class has a defaulted copy-constructor, which does not log anything, of course.

So, what you're really seeing is both the original object's and the copy's destructor getting invoked. Nothing gets logged for the copy construction.

You will see the entire picture of what's happening after you add an explicit copy constructor that logs which instance of the object gets copy-constructed.

> I add their unique_ptr to a vector?

No, you're not doing that. You're creating a copy of each object, in dynamic scope, with `make_unique` (because that's what it does), and add the newly-constructed copy's `unique_ptr` to the vector.